# Apache-camel with spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm trying to set up a project with the stack on title, the JMS that we're using is ActiveMQ. So, here is the configuration that I'm doing:

```
@SpringBootApplication

public class Application {

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Application.class);

@Value("${broker.component.name}")
private String brokerComponetName;
@Value("${broker.dead.letter.queue}")
private String brokerDeadLetterQueue;
@Value("${broker.in.queue}")
private String brokerInQueue;
@Value("${broker.out.queue}")
private String brokerOutQueue;
@Value("${broker.url}")
private String brokerUrl;
@Value("${broker.user}")
private String brokerUser;
@Value("${broker.password}")
private String brokerPassword;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    logger.info("starting loader");
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Bean
public SpringCamelContext camelContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws Exception {

    SpringCamelContext camelContext = new SpringCamelContext(applicationContext);

    camelContext.addComponent(brokerComponetName, JmsComponent.jmsComponent(connectionFactory()));

    camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() throws ConfigurationException {
            errorHandler(deadLetterChannel(brokerDeadLetterQueue)
                    .onRedelivery(new FailureProcessor())
                    .useOriginalMessage()
                    .maximumRedeliveries(5)
                    .redeliveryDelay(5000)
                    .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.INFO));

            from(brokerInQueue)
                .process(new MessageProcessor())
                .to(brokerOutQueue);
        }
    });

    return camelContext;
}

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws ConfigurationException {
    System.out.println("BROKER URL: " + brokerUrl);
    return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUser,
            brokerPassword, brokerUrl);
}
```

I already tried to add @EnableJms to Application with no success. The stack error is the follow:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jmsListenerContainerFactory' defined in class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/JmsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory]:
>   Factory method 'jmsListenerContainerFactory' threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setAutoStartup(Z)V

Thank's in advanced and sorry about any mistake in question.

Comment: Have you tried with camel spring boot package? That's pretty easy please have a look at https://github.com/vivek-dhayalan/camel_cxfrs_spring_boot_java_dsl for sample with spring boot and let me know if it's helpful.

Comment: A nice example Vivek of using spring boot and Camel together - i like that.

Comment: I tried, but doesn't fit to my necessity. But it's a great example.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's a bug of spring boot 1.3.3:
DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory does not contains the required method.
Try to upgrade to spring boot 1.4.0 (in spite it is not in RELEASE version at the moment). 
That should solve the bug.

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue by upgrading to spring boot 1.4.0? I could not find maven dependency for 1.4.0.M1 or M2 version. Can you help me with same?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same Exception and read the answers here. Because I'm using Spring boot 1.5.1-RELEASE, I found the answers not to be applicable and continued my search.
What I found to be the cause on my end was not properly reading the manual:
http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html. The introduction states:

> To use this component make sure you have the activemq.jar or activemq-core.jar on your classpath along with any Camel dependencies such as camel-core.jar, camel-spring.jar and camel-jms.jar.

So what solved the problem was 2 extra Maven entries.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
  <version>${apache.camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
  <version>${apache.camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody meet with this issue I found solution.

We need to downgrade version of spring-boot to 1.2.3.RELEASE, because camel-jms:2.16.2 uses spring components in version 4.1.9.